# Replace multiple matches of the same string with different patterns in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a set of data frames where, in each one, there are multiple occurrences of the same string in a column, but they really reflect different observations.

```
library(dplyr)
govs <- c("Government", "Federal", "General government", "Government enterprises", "State and local", 
          "General government", "Government enterprises")
df <- data.frame("gov_levels" = govs, revenue = rnorm(7, mean = 1000, sd = 50))
df
```

I would like to replace (or concatenate) each occurrence with a different pattern so they become distinct.  This code will return the desired output,

```
    df %>% 
    mutate(gov_levels = stri_replace_first_fixed(str = gov_levels, pattern = "General government", 
                                    replacement = c("Federal general government", 
                                                    "State and local general government")))
```

but it is inconsistent depending on whether "General government" is in an even- or odd-numbered row, as illustrated when I remove the first row before mutating:

```
    df %>%
    filter(gov_levels != "Government") %>%
    mutate(gov_levels = stri_replace_first_fixed(str = gov_levels, pattern = "General government", 
                                           replacement = c("Federal general government", 
                                                           "State and local general government")))
```

This results in the replacements occurring in the wrong order.  I am looking for a way to apply this consistently so that it is not dependent on the row position of the strings to be replaced.  That is, the first match will always be replaced by *Federal* General Government and the second will always be replaced by *State and Local* General Government.

UPDATES BASED ON GEORGE'S ANSWER
List of data frames with some inconsistencies:

```
govs <- c("Government", "Federal", "General government", "Government enterprises", "State and local", 
          "General government", "Government enterprises", NA, NA)

df1 <- data.frame("col_1" = "col1data", "gov_levels" = govs, revenue = c(rnorm(7, mean = 100, sd = 50), NA, NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame("col_1" = "col1data", "gov_types" = govs, revenue = c(rnorm(7, mean = 100, sd = 50), NA, NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- df2 %>%
       filter(gov_types != "Government")

df_list <- list(df1, df2)
```

And implementing George's solution with lapply to deal with the other issues I mentioned - I am curious if there is a better way to approach this?

```
newlevels_gen <- c("Federal general government", "State and local general government")

df_list <- lapply(df_list, 
                  function(x) {x[, 2] <- as.factor(x[, 2]) 
                               return(x)
                               }
                  )

df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {levels(x[,2]) <- c(levels(x[,2]), newlevels_gen)
                                        return(x)
                                        }
                  )

df_list_clean_a <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {x[,2][!is.na(x[,2]) & x[,2] == "General government"] <- newlevels_gen 
                                               return(x)
                                               } 
                         )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this achieve your goal?  Just replace the elements that meet your condition with the required string vector.  But first you need to add to the allowed levels for your factor or you'll get an error.

```
# First define a string containing the new levels for the 'gov_levels' factor
newlevels <- c("Federal general government", "State and local general government")

# Then add them so that they are allowed as factor levels
levels(df$gov_levels) <- c(levels(df$gov_levels), newlevels)

# Now just replace the values where 'gov_levels' is "General government" with the new string
# They will naturally be assigned in the same order they occur in the dataset
df$gov_levels[df$gov_levels=="General government"] <- newlevels
```

Of course this will only work if there are exactly two occurrences, but I guess from your question this is the case?  If there's two or fewer then we can adjust the last line to count the number of occurrences needed.

**Edit**

If the vector `gov_levels` is a character vector not a factor, then you don't need to worry about the levels and you can just do:

```
df$gov_levels[df$gov_levels=="General government"] <- 
      c("Federal general government", "State and local general")
```

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful.  Yes it is always a situation where I need to match those two occurrences and differentiate between Federal and S&L.  I am working with a list of similar data frames so I am working on extending this solution for use with lapply.  This raises a few issues: 1) The "gov_levels" column is of chr type, rather than factor across all dfs, 2) There are NAs in the column, 3) The column names are different in some data frames.  This makes it a little less straightforward, but I think I have a solution for it.

Comment: @CaseyR if your vector was a character vector to start with then you don't need the `levels` bit at all.  I will edit..

Comment: I am not sure why the NAs are an issue either, but I get the error message "Error in x[, 2][x[, 2] == "General government"] <- newlevels_gen : 
NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments" when I do that last assignment step (df_list_clean_a) unless I include the & !is.na(x[,2]) within the subsetting brackets.  Maybe it can't evaluate the NA values as either TRUE or FALSE when checking that they equal "General government"? It may work when doing column selection with $ as in your example, but as I mentioned the column name is inconsistent across the multiple data frames.

Comment: I should add, the column names are different, but the relevant data is always the second column.

Comment: @CaseyR good point subscripted assignments can't have `NA`.  Since you know its the second column then just use `[,2]` as you have done?  Is there a further issue?

Comment: No further issues, I consider it solved, unless you had a suggestion for improving the lapply() I used to iterate across each dataframe in my list.  Thanks for your help!